# Changing the icon of an exe file in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, exe

How can i change the icon of an exe file in windows7.I am asking about changing the icon of application itself not shortcut because i know that there is a way to change the icon of a shortcut.

Comment: If "you may be able to get help on Super User", why on Earth wasn't this migrated to Super User?

Comment: If the answer to this was 'general-computing-related' then the answer wouldn't be 'download and use this third-party app'.  This really should not be closed.

Comment: This is absolutely related to programming and software development. For example, Electron apps require distributing the Electron executable and it's very-much expected that one would want to ['rebrand' the executable](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-distribution/#rebranding-with-downloaded-binaries).

Comment: You could also use shimgen to create another exe that points to the old one with a different icon

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker) can do this.

[How to Modify the Icon of an .Exe File](http://howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file)

Comment: nope doesn't work for me

Comment: For @xiaodai and future readers: If changing the icon in the exe doesn't seem to work, then check any dlls that come with the program, as they may also have icons that need to be replaced. This was the case with [clover](http://ejie.me/).

Comment: Would it work for signed executables, anybody knows?