# What is the best way to restore previous Android Studio icon?

Tags: android-studio

With the new Android Studio 4.1 we received a new icon. I don't like it and want to restore the previous one. I most interested in the solution for Windows 10, but I think macOS users could be also interested.

Comment: For Windows see this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370553/changing-the-icon-of-an-exe-file-in-windows-7.

Comment: @mrpasqal thank you for your input, now I must check if toolbox will also respect this, and think how make it more pleasant in use in case of future android studio updates, which are install in different directories